# Issues with fade effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I cannot get the automated text to work on an android. It only shows the first text/ image. note: all the images are now currently the same.

Also, I am trying to get rid of the flash effect on the screen. I am using a static background and just want animated text. Maybe there is a better way to code this and have it work on android?

Here is the site: www.juliandavislaw.com

Thanks for any input.

Comment: can you show where you are having problems? your question is very vague. Is there a part of the code that is not working or not behaving as expected?

Comment: sorry for being vague. It is a basic question. I am trying to get the text to change while having a stagnant background without the flash like effect hat is currently there on the background. A flash effect on the text only is ok but not necessary.

Comment: The flash is most probably from the plugin  you are using (flexslider) you should check their documentation

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem , you want to change your text at some specified intervals, for that you can use following javascript code:

```
var counter = 0;
        setInterval(function()
        {
            counter++;
            switch (counter)
            {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML = "Shoaib";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML = "Lara";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML = "Robert";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    counter=0;
                    document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML = "John";
                    break;
            }
        },500);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myTag"></div>
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8X3Zx/) .

Hope this helps.